# how to create basic level DataFrame by using dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this

[image]

but I want to create DataFrame like this ;

[image]

Actually, I just want to append salary up to min, max and mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
df = df.set_index('department_name')
# add salary as level=0 column name
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['salary'], df.columns])
```